# Export Javadoc to html in InteliJ

Tags: html, intellij-idea, javadoc

Is there a plugin for IntelliJ to export the Javadoc to HTML files?

Is there a way to do that?

it is a Maven Project using Junit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either [Generate JavaDoc Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-code-documentation.html) in IntelliJ IDEA directly or [do it via Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/).